# Sphinx arabic search

Tags: php, utf-8, character, sphinx

I'm working on a multilingual site (English, Arabic and French) and using sphinx search. I'm running into an issue when searching the for an Arabic name in the relatives fields. The relatives field is saved in the database as such (PHP json_encode is used to save it in the DB):

`{"husband":"","wife":"\u0645\u0627\u0631\u064a \u0623\u0631\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0643 \u0645\u0648\u0645\u062c\u064a\u0627\u0646","father":"","mother":"","children":"\u0632\u064a\u0627\u062f \u0628\u0637\u0631\u0633\r\n\u062c\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0627 \u0628\u0637\u0631\u0633 \u0632\u0648\u062c\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0627\u0626\u0628 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0627\u0633 \u0628\u0648 \u0635\u0639\u0628 \u0648\u0639\u0627\u0626\u0644\u062a\u0647\u0645\u0627\r\n\u0635\u0648\u0641\u064a \u0628\u0637\u0631\u0633 \u0632\u0648\u062c\u0629 \u062c\u0648\u0632\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0647\u0646\u062f\u064a \u0648\u0639\u0627\u0626\u0644\u062a\u0647\u0645\u0627","sisters":"","brothers":"","relatives":"\u0648\u0639\u0627\u0626\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0628\u0637\u0631\u0633\u060c \u0645\u0648\u0645\u062c\u064a\u0627\u0646\u060c \u0628\u0648 \u0635\u0639\u0628\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0647\u0646\u062f\u064a \u0648\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0628\u0627\u0624\u0647\u0645 \u064a\u0646\u0639\u0648\u0646 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645 \u0641\u0642\u064a\u062f\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0648\u0645"}`

When i search for the word: `جوليا` no results are found, although the word is in the field in the form of hexadecimal entities `\u062c\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0627`

My sphinx.conf:

```
#
# Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)
#

source graves
{
        type                    = mysql

        sql_host                = localhost
        sql_user                = root
        sql_pass                = 
        sql_db                  = memorialsv2
        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

        sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES 'utf8'

        sql_query               = \
                SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateOfDeath) AS dateOfDeath, firstName, middleName, lastName FROM graves \
        WHERE status = 'published'

        sql_attr_timestamp      = dateOfDeath

}

source memorials : graves
{
        sql_query               = \
                SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateOfDeath) AS date, firstName,middleName,lastName,biography FROM memorials \
        WHERE status = 'published'

                sql_attr_timestamp      = date

}

source obituary : graves
{
        sql_query               = \
                SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateOfDeath) AS dateOfDeath, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateOfPublish) AS dateOfPublish, firstName, middleName, lastName, contents, relatives_families, categoryId, relatives FROM obituaries \
        WHERE status = 'published'

                sql_attr_timestamp      = dateOfDeath
                sql_attr_timestamp      = dateOfPublish
                sql_attr_uint                       = categoryId

}

index graves
{
        source                  = graves
        path                    = c:/sphinx/data/graves
        docinfo                 = extern
        #min_prefix_len         = 2
        min_infix_len           = 2
        #morphology             = stem_en, stem_ar
        #ignore_chars            = U+064B..U+0660
        charset_table           = 0..9, a..z, A..Z->a..z, U+640..U+64a, U+66e..U+66f, U+671..U+6d3, U+6d5, U+6e5..U+6e6, U+6ee..U+6ef, U+6fa..U+6fc, U+6ff, U+0622->U+0627, U+0623->U+0627, U+0624->U+0648, U+0625->U+0627, U+0626->U+064A, U+FE8D->U+0627, U+06C0->U+06D5, U+06C2->U+06C1, U+06D3->U+06D2, U+FB50->U+0671, U+FB51->U+0671, U+FB52->U+067B, U+FB53->U+067B, U+FB54->U+067B, U+FB56->U+067E, U+FB57->U+067E, U+FB58->U+067E, U+FB5A->U+0680, U+FB5B->U+0680, U+FB5C->U+0680, U+FB5E->U+067A, U+FB5F->U+067A, U+FB60->U+067A, U+FB62->U+067F, U+FB63->U+067F, U+FB64->U+067F, U+FB66->U+0679, U+FB67->U+0679, U+FB68->U+0679, U+FB6A->U+06A4, U+FB6B->U+06A4, U+FB6C->U+06A4, U+FB6E->U+06A6, U+FB6F->U+06A6, U+FB70->U+06A6, U+FB72->U+0684, U+FB73->U+0684, U+FB74->U+0684, U+FB76->U+0683, U+FB77->U+0683, U+FB78->U+0683, U+FB7A->U+0686, U+FB7B->U+0686, U+FB7C->U+0686, U+FB7E->U+0687, U+FB7F->U+0687, U+FB80->U+0687, U+FB82->U+068D, U+FB83->U+068D, U+FB84->U+068C, U+FB85->U+068C, U+FB86->U+068E, U+FB87->U+068E, U+FB88->U+0688, U+FB89->U+0688, U+FB8A->U+0698, U+FB8B->U+0698, U+FB8C->U+0691, U+FB8D->U+0691, U+FB8E->U+06A9, U+FB8F->U+06A9, U+FB90->U+06A9, U+FB92->U+06AF, U+FB93->U+06AF, U+FB94->U+06AF, U+FB96->U+06B3, U+FB97->U+06B3, U+FB98->U+06B3, U+FB9A->U+06B1, U+FB9B->U+06B1, U+FB9C->U+06B1, U+FB9E->U+06BA, U+FB9F->U+06BA, U+FBA0->U+06BB, U+FBA1->U+06BB, U+FBA2->U+06BB, U+FBA4->U+06C0, U+FBA5->U+06C0, U+FBA6->U+06C1, U+FBA7->U+06C1, U+FBA8->U+06C1, U+FBAA->U+06BE, U+FBAB->U+06BE, U+FBAC->U+06BE, U+FBAE->U+06D2, U+FBAF->U+06D2, U+FBB0->U+06D3, U+FBB1->U+06D3, U+FBD3->U+06AD, U+FBD4->U+06AD, U+FBD5->U+06AD, U+FBD7->U+06C7, U+FBD8->U+06C7, U+FBD9->U+06C6, U+FBDA->U+06C6, U+FBDB->U+06C8, U+FBDC->U+06C8, U+FBDD->U+0677, U+FBDE->U+06CB, U+FBDF->U+06CB, U+FBE0->U+06C5, U+FBE1->U+06C5, U+FBE2->U+06C9, U+FBE3->U+06C9, U+FBE4->U+06D0, U+FBE5->U+06D0, U+FBE6->U+06D0, U+FBE8->U+0649, U+FBFC->U+06CC, U+FBFD->U+06CC, U+FBFE->U+06CC, U+0621, U+0627..U+063A, U+0641..U+064A, U+0660..U+0669, U+066E, U+066F, U+0671..U+06BF, U+06C1, U+06C3..U+06D2, U+06D5, U+06EE..U+06FC, U+06FF, U+0750..U+076D, U+FB55, U+FB59, U+FB5D, U+FB61, U+FB65, U+FB69, U+FB6D, U+FB71, U+FB75, U+FB79, U+FB7D, U+FB81, U+FB91, U+FB95, U+FB99, U+FB9D, U+FBA3, U+FBA9, U+FBAD, U+FBD6, U+FBE7, U+FBE9, U+FBFF, U+00C0->a, U+00C1->a,U+00C2->a, U+00C3->a, U+00C4->a, U+00C5->a, U+00C7->c, U+00C8->e,U+00C9->e, U+00CA->e, U+00CB->e, U+00CC->i, U+00CD->i, U+00CE->i,U+00CF->i, U+00D1->n, U+00D2->o, U+00D3->o, U+00D4->o, U+00D5->o,U+00D6->o, U+00D9->u, U+00DA->u, U+00DB->u, U+00DC->u, U+00DD->y,U+00E0->a, U+00E1->a, U+00E2->a, U+00E3->a, U+00E4->a, U+00E5->a,U+00E7->c, U+00E8->e, U+00E9->e, U+00EA->e, U+00EB->e, U+00EC->i,U+00ED->i, U+00EE->i, U+00EF->i, U+00F1->n, U+00F2->o, U+00F3->o,U+00F4->o, U+00F5->o, U+00F6->o, U+00F9->u, U+00FA->u, U+00FB->u,U+00FC->u, U+00FD->y, U+00FF->y, U+0100->a, U+0101->a, U+0102->a,U+0103->a, U+0104->a, U+0105->a, U+0106->c, U+0107->c, U+0108->c,U+0109->c, U+010A->c, U+010B->c, U+010C->c, U+010D->c, U+010E->d,U+010F->d, U+0112->e, U+0113->e, U+0114->e, U+0115->e, U+0116->e,U+0117->e, U+0118->e, U+0119->e, U+011A->e, U+011B->e, U+011C->g,U+011D->g, U+011E->g, U+011F->g, U+0120->g, U+0121->g, U+0122->g,U+0123->g, U+0124->h, U+0125->h, U+0128->i, U+0129->i, U+012A->i,U+012B->i, U+012C->i, U+012D->i, U+012E->i, U+012F->i, U+0130->i,U+0134->j, U+0135->j, U+0136->k, U+0137->k, U+0139->l, U+013A->l,U+013B->l, U+013C->l, U+013D->l, U+013E->l, U+0142->l, U+0143->n,U+0144->n, U+0145->n, U+0146->n, U+0147->n, U+0148->n, U+014C->o,U+014D->o, U+014E->o, U+014F->o, U+0150->o, U+0151->o, U+0154->r,U+0155->r, U+0156->r, U+0157->r, U+0158->r, U+0159->r, U+015A->s,U+015B->s, U+015C->s, U+015D->s, U+015E->s, U+015F->s, U+0160->s,U+0161->s, U+0162->t, U+0163->t, U+0164->t, U+0165->t, U+0168->u,U+0169->u, U+016A->u, U+016B->u, U+016C->u, U+016D->u, U+016E->u,U+016F->u, U+0170->u, U+0171->u, U+0172->u, U+0173->u, U+0174->w,U+0175->w, U+0176->y, U+0177->y, U+0178->y, U+0179->z, U+017A->z,U+017B->z, U+017C->z, U+017D->z, U+017E->z, U+01A0->o, U+01A1->o,U+01AF->u, U+01B0->u, U+01CD->a, U+01CE->a, U+01CF->i, U+01D0->i,U+01D1->o, U+01D2->o, U+01D3->u, U+01D4->u, U+01D5->u, U+01D6->u,U+01D7->u, U+01D8->u, U+01D9->u, U+01DA->u, U+01DB->u, U+01DC->u,U+01DE->a, U+01DF->a, U+01E0->a, U+01E1->a, U+01E6->g, U+01E7->g,U+01E8->k, U+01E9->k, U+01EA->o, U+01EB->o, U+01EC->o, U+01ED->o,U+01F0->j, U+01F4->g, U+01F5->g, U+01F8->n, U+01F9->n, U+01FA->a,U+01FB->a, U+0200->a, U+0201->a, U+0202->a, U+0203->a, U+0204->e,U+0205->e, U+0206->e, U+0207->e, U+0208->i, U+0209->i, U+020A->i,U+020B->i, U+020C->o, U+020D->o, U+020E->o, U+020F->o, U+0210->r,U+0211->r, U+0212->r, U+0213->r, U+0214->u, U+0215->u, U+0216->u,U+0217->u, U+0218->s, U+0219->s, U+021A->t, U+021B->t, U+021E->h,U+021F->h, U+0226->a, U+0227->a, U+0228->e, U+0229->e, U+022A->o,U+022B->o, U+022C->o, U+022D->o, U+022E->o, U+022F->o, U+0230->o,U+0231->o, U+0232->y, U+0233->y, U+1E00->a, U+1E01->a, U+1E02->b,U+1E03->b, U+1E04->b, U+1E05->b, U+1E06->b, U+1E07->b, U+1E08->c,U+1E09->c, U+1E0A->d, U+1E0B->d, U+1E0C->d, U+1E0D->d, U+1E0E->d,U+1E0F->d, U+1E10->d, U+1E11->d, U+1E12->d, U+1E13->d, U+1E14->e,U+1E15->e, U+1E16->e, U+1E17->e, U+1E18->e, U+1E19->e, U+1E1A->e,U+1E1B->e, U+1E1C->e, U+1E1D->e, U+1E1E->f, U+1E1F->f, U+1E20->g,U+1E21->g, U+1E22->h, U+1E23->h, U+1E24->h, U+1E25->h, U+1E26->h,U+1E27->h, U+1E28->h, U+1E29->h, U+1E2A->h, U+1E2B->h, U+1E2C->i,U+1E2D->i, U+1E2E->i, U+1E2F->i, U+1E30->k, U+1E31->k, U+1E32->k,U+1E33->k, U+1E34->k, U+1E35->k, U+1E36->l, U+1E37->l, U+1E38->l,U+1E39->l, U+1E3A->l, U+1E3B->l, U+1E3C->l, U+1E3D->l, U+1E3E->m,U+1E3F->m, U+1E40->m, U+1E41->m, U+1E42->m, U+1E43->m, U+1E44->n,U+1E45->n, U+1E46->n, U+1E47->n, U+1E48->n, U+1E49->n, U+1E4A->n,U+1E4B->n, U+1E4C->o, U+1E4D->o, U+1E4E->o, U+1E4F->o, U+1E50->o,U+1E51->o, U+1E52->o, U+1E53->o, U+1E54->p, U+1E55->p, U+1E56->p,U+1E57->p, U+1E58->r, U+1E59->r, U+1E5A->r, U+1E5B->r, U+1E5C->r,U+1E5D->r, U+1E5E->r, U+1E5F->r, U+1E60->s, U+1E61->s, U+1E62->s,U+1E63->s, U+1E64->s, U+1E65->s, U+1E66->s, U+1E67->s, U+1E68->s,U+1E69->s, U+1E6A->t, U+1E6B->t, U+1E6C->t, U+1E6D->t, U+1E6E->t,U+1E6F->t, U+1E70->t, U+1E71->t, U+1E72->u, U+1E73->u, U+1E74->u,U+1E75->u, U+1E76->u, U+1E77->u, U+1E78->u, U+1E79->u, U+1E7A->u,U+1E7B->u, U+1E7C->v, U+1E7D->v, U+1E7E->v, U+1E7F->v, U+1E80->w,U+1E81->w, U+1E82->w, U+1E83->w, U+1E84->w, U+1E85->w, U+1E86->w,U+1E87->w, U+1E88->w, U+1E89->w, U+1E8A->x, U+1E8B->x, U+1E8C->x,U+1E8D->x, U+1E8E->y, U+1E8F->y, U+1E96->h, U+1E97->t, U+1E98->w,U+1E99->y, U+1EA0->a, U+1EA1->a, U+1EA2->a, U+1EA3->a, U+1EA4->a,U+1EA5->a, U+1EA6->a, U+1EA7->a, U+1EA8->a, U+1EA9->a, U+1EAA->a,U+1EAB->a, U+1EAC->a, U+1EAD->a, U+1EAE->a, U+1EAF->a, U+1EB0->a,U+1EB1->a, U+1EB2->a, U+1EB3->a, U+1EB4->a, U+1EB5->a, U+1EB6->a,U+1EB7->a, U+1EB8->e, U+1EB9->e, U+1EBA->e, U+1EBB->e, U+1EBC->e,U+1EBD->e, U+1EBE->e, U+1EBF->e, U+1EC0->e, U+1EC1->e, U+1EC2->e,U+1EC3->e, U+1EC4->e, U+1EC5->e, U+1EC6->e, U+1EC7->e, U+1EC8->i,U+1EC9->i, U+1ECA->i, U+1ECB->i, U+1ECC->o, U+1ECD->o, U+1ECE->o,U+1ECF->o, U+1ED0->o, U+1ED1->o, U+1ED2->o, U+1ED3->o, U+1ED4->o,U+1ED5->o, U+1ED6->o, U+1ED7->o, U+1ED8->o, U+1ED9->o, U+1EDA->o,U+1EDB->o, U+1EDC->o, U+1EDD->o, U+1EDE->o, U+1EDF->o, U+1EE0->o,U+1EE1->o, U+1EE2->o, U+1EE3->o, U+1EE4->u, U+1EE5->u, U+1EE6->u,U+1EE7->u, U+1EE8->u, U+1EE9->u, U+1EEA->u, U+1EEB->u, U+1EEC->u,U+1EED->u, U+1EEE->u, U+1EEF->u, U+1EF0->u, U+1EF1->u, U+1EF2->y,U+1EF3->y, U+1EF4->y, U+1EF5->y, U+1EF6->y, U+1EF7->y, U+1EF8->y,U+1EF9->y
}

index memorials : graves
{
        source = memorials
        path                    = c:/sphinx/data/memorials
}

index obituary : graves
{
        source = obituary
        path                    = c:/sphinx/data/obituary
}


indexer
{
        mem_limit               = 256M
}

searchd
{
            binlog_path             = #
        listen                  = 9312
        listen                  = 9306:mysql41
        log                     = c:/sphinx/log/searchd.log
        query_log               = c:/sphinx/log/query.log
        read_timeout            = 5
        max_children            = 30
        pid_file                = c:/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
        #max_matches            = 1000
        seamless_rotate         = 1
        preopen_indexes         = 1
        unlink_old              = 1
        workers                 = threads # for RT to work
        #compat_sphinxql_magics = 0
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> PHP json_encode is used to save it in the DB

makes me think that what you have in the DB is not text in Arabic, but text in Latin, i.e. not "م", but "\u0645" which is wrong both in terms of storing it in MySQL (requires more space) and fetching from MySQL in Sphinx. So my recommendation is to not use json_encode() to store it in MySQL, but store it as is. If you have an encoding issue you'd better take an effort to solve it rather than storing codes instead of the real characters.

> When i search for the word: جوليا no results are found, although the
>   word is in the field in the form of hexadecimal entities
>   \u062c\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0627
>   Sphinx doesn't work like this. It doesn't convert from codes to characters neither during indexing nor during search. You have to provide it real characters. The only place where the codes are to be specified is charset_table.

P.S. If you use Manticore Search (fork of Sphinx) you can just do `charset_table = non_cjk` which should be enough in most cases and makes your config much easier to maintain.